# How to implement the equivalent of the Win32 function MessageBox in PHP/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I already have a working PHP function that outputs a JQuery UI dialog with almost the same prototype ( MessageBox($text, $caption, $flags) where $flags is an unsigned int (flags can be passed like that: MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING ).

This is working perfectly. My problem is how to get values back from the popup?
It can have OK, CANCEL, RETRY, etc, buttons, and I would like to know if its possible to know which button has been pressed client-side from the PHP.
Typically, the function should return 1 if OK has been pressed, 2 if CANCEL has been pressed, etc.

I've looked at AJAX and regular form posting, but it seems impossible to just do:

```
$userInput = MessageBox("Would you like to delete this line?", "WARNING", MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONWARNING);
```

(See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) for the Win32 function)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how work Win32 function, but I think in javascript it maybe this:

```
if (confirm('Would you like to delete this line?')) {
    // Delete it!
} else {
    // Do something!
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does work but doesn't solve my problem (the Jquery UI dialog is just a "buffed" alert/confirm), which is to get back the user input to the PHP

Comment: Ok, and ajax request from client-side to server side in confirm condition does not suit for you?

Something like that:

if (confirm('Would you like to delete this line?')) {
    $.post("/server_handler.php", { id: 123 }, function( data ) { alert('deleting complete.'); });
} else {
    // Do something!
}

Comment: Well the confirm works but its limited for what we wanted to do, but maybe we were too ambitious haha. Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

AJAX and regular form posting are your only options, really. That's how the client talks to the server on the web. You can't really "show a dialog" in PHP - you're doing it in JavaScript (via jQuery). JavaScript/jQuery code will have to handle which button was clicked and communicate this back to PHP. Answering in more detail isn't really possible in a question/answer format. I suggest giving AJAX a try and see if you come up with a more specific question we can answer instead.

Comment: I wanted something more dynamic, but after some more research and your answer it seems that we will have to do with ajax and form posting. Thank you for the answer anyway!